# MySQL real escape - Own escape - o to ö?

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I want to escape all my strings I want to insert in my database. But my problem is, because I have more than 10.000 strings to check, the database queries would be too much...

So I use this escape function, which I found here in stackoverflow.com:

```
function escape($value) {
    $return = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); ++$i) {
        $char = $value[$i];
        $ord = ord($char);
        if($char !== "'" && $char !== "\"" && $char !== '\\' && $ord >= 32 && $ord <= 126)
            $return .= $char;
        else
            $return .= '\\x' . dechex($ord);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

It's working. But my problem is, that I do not have any `ö`, `ä` or chars like that...

Before I call this function I have a string like this: `Königsedition` and after I called this function, I should get `K\xc3\x83\xc2\xb6nigsedition`. But the problem is, that for some reasons I get `Kxc3xb6nigsedition` in my database...

How can I turn this back to `Königsedition`?

**Or**, is there a other way to escape the string, without using the SQL real escape function, because then I must to more than 10.000 SQL Queries, to escape a string and to keep the `UTF 8` formatting? (I would prefer this way!)

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: What about parameterized query?

Comment: "for some reason" you get a string in your database... not from calling that  "escape" function you don't. You would get a string in your database because you executed an INSERT or UPDATE statement.  If you are inserting the string return from that "escape" function, then that would be a "reason" you are getting a string in your database. I'm not understanding why you would expect a string *different* from the one you inserted to be in the database. Why do you "use this escape function"? I'm not understanding the purpose.

Comment: Just use a prepared statement with bind placeholders, and supply the value of the string you want inserted. Make sure the encoding of the strings passed as values *match* the characterset specified for the MySQL client and columns.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to 'escape' to the encoding of your strings. Make sure the table, the connection and your input all have the same encoding (like UTF-8).

For your table make sure the columns (and preferably the table itself) have i.e. utf8_general_ci collation.

If you use PDO, add `;charset:utf8` to your DSN or if you don't use PDO, execute the query `SET NAMES utf8` before running the other queries. An example of a DSN with charset would be `mysql:host=HOSTNAME;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8`.

Make sure your pages have the UTF-8 encoding, send the Content-Type header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` for HTML pages so browsers will send content (by forms) in UTF-8.

Comment: Why do you need to 'escape', if you simply use parameterized queries or PDO's `quote()` method, you should be fine

Comment: The collation is also important. Just UTF-8 isn't enough. Make sure as @Dygnus said that all of your tables (and DB) are set to utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci -- all the same whichever collation you choose.